# MATLAB: fmincon can't find a minimum value

Tags: matlab

run:

```
function test()

Aeq = ones(1,4); beq = 1;
a0 = [.2,.2,.2,.1];
[a,f] = fmincon(@ttest,a0,[],[],Aeq,beq);
```

Result:

```
Warning: Trust-region-reflective algorithm does not solve
this type of problem, using active-set algorithm. You
could also try the interior-point or sqp algorithms: set
the Algorithm option to 'interior-point' or 'sqp' and
rerun. For more help, see Choosing the Algorithm in the
documentation. 
> In fmincon at 472
  In test at 6

Local minimum found that satisfies the constraints.

Optimization completed because the objective function is non-decreasing in 
feasible directions, to within the default value of the function tolerance,
and constraints were satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>
```

I have tested 'ttest', it works fine.....don't quite understand the warning~~ Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What does your `ttest` function look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local minimization succeeded: `Local minimum found that satisfies the constraints.`
. Check your values of `a` and `f`.

All the warning is telling you is that the default algorithm doesn't work for the problem you are working with, so it picks another one for you. See the [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fmincon.html) documentation near the bottom for the different algorithms it can use. You can get rid of this warning by telling it specifically which algorithm to use:

```
Aeq = ones(1,4); beq = 1;
a0 = [.2,.2,.2,.1];
options = optimset('Display', 'iter', ...
                   'Algorithm', 'active-set');
[a,f] = fmincon(@ttest,a0,[],[],Aeq,beq,[],[],[],options);
```

I've also told it to display its iterations, something I always find useful in the debugging phase. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/f19175.html) for the various options available.